# Is there a workaround to Enum PCL non-support?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, portable-class-library

Working on code I am converting to a Portable Class Library in Mono, I came across a section that uses `System.IO.WebExceptionStatus` to switch what to do after getting a response. My problem is only part of this enumeration is supported as a PCL.

e.g. `ConnectionClosed` is not inside the enum for PCL building.

So two questions really:
1) Why is only part of the Enum supported (I can't find why anywhere)?
2) Is there a PCL workaround that allows me to have approximate behavior?

Answer (score 1):

1) Based on [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx), Windows Store application profile only supports a limited set of the items. In this case, PCL can only support that set of items.

2) If you application do need to handle other items, don't put that piece of code in the PCL.

Comment: 1) I got that, but why that subset? I have found documentation of other restrictions, but not that enum. 2) So completely drop half the number of possible outcomes...

Comment: Microsoft never documents why an API is removed for a certain profile (such as CF, Silverlight, Windows Store, XBox). The only assumption I can think of is that for Windows Store apps, the underlying CLR runtime makes sure that only when the set of web exception occurs the application is notified.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean -       System.Net.WebException 
"WebException Class"

- System.Object

  - System.Exception
  - System.SystemException
  - System.InvalidOperationException
  - System.Net.WebException

*.NET Framework 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0| 
Client Profile: 4, 3.5 SP1``
Portable Class Library
.NET for Windows Store apps Supported in: Windows 8*

its been said a million times but pcl its just a wrapper for a common denominator or intersection between platform implementations.

and I think it has to be because of the `[__DynamicallyInvokable]` attribute

Similar situation as with Stream.Close() vs Stream.Dispose() , you are going to need to switch usage or find workarounds, in the case of an enum it could be possible to cast to int and check for it's value.

```
// Type: System.Net.WebExceptionStatus
// Assembly: System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
namespace System.Net
{
  public enum WebExceptionStatus
  {
    Success = 0,
    ConnectFailure = 2,
    SendFailure = 4,
    RequestCanceled = 6,
    Pending = 13,
    UnknownError = 16,
    MessageLengthLimitExceeded = 17,
  }
}
```

---

```
 try
{
//Do something that can throw WebException ? 
}
catch (WebException e)
{
if((int)e.Status  == 0)
Debug.WriteLine("Success"); 
}

var test = new Class1.Test();
test.Run();
```

or try the known types?

```
try                        
{
//Do something that can throw WebException ? 
}
catch (WebException e)
{
if (e.Status == (WebExceptionStatus.Success) ||
    e.Status == (WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure) ||
    e.Status == (WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled) ||
    e.Status == (WebExceptionStatus.Pending) ||
    e.Status == (WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError) ||
    e.Status == (WebExceptionStatus.MessageLengthLimitExceeded))
    Debug.WriteLine("Ok");
else
    Debug.WriteLine("Its another WebException");                          
}
```